# How do I add a navigation bar's Done button to a popover's passthroughViews?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

I'm working in an iPad app that has a split view with a navigation controller in the detail view. The deepest view that can be in the navigation stack is an edit view where the user can edit data. I put an edit button as the rightBarButtonItem and when editing starts, change it to a done button.

When editing commences and the user touches on a particular field, I present a popoverview with a list of possible choices filtered by what they are typing - a form of autofill based on all the values of that field in all other objects.

This works fine, except if you try touching on the done button. The popover eats this touch and dismisses itself. So the user has to touch done again.

I tried using the uipopovercontroller's passthroughViews property, but UIBarButtonItem is not a view and there is no documented way to get the view for the done button or even the navigation bar. I can access the variable in gdb, but it isn't accessible via KVC.

Any ideas on how I can prevent the need to tap done twice?

I've thought about a gesture recognizer on the window, but that seems messy and I'd have to handle rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone gets here from google, copypaste from other question:

The only solution I found for now is to create UIBarButtonItem with custom UIButton using

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//code for styling button

UIBarButtonItem *b =  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                         initWithCustomView:button]
                                         autorelease]
```

and then

```
popoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:b.customView];
```

But be prepared - you cannot create UIButton that looks like UIBarButtoItem. I ended up with creating image that reassembled UIBarButtonItem.